# How to merge two documents without overwriting elements in original using XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am a new to XSLT and I need to insert an xslt script into a third party software, which uses XSLT 1.0 to transform xml document.

My task is to take document A.xml and insert each element from document B.xml, but only if the text in A is not yet existing. The output should be generated as document C.xml.

Example A.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
    <Table>
        <Name>SCHAME.table_name</Name>
        <Location>oracle:TNS_1</Location>
        <Citation>
            <Title>Title 1</Title>
            <Description/>
        </Citation>
        <metadataDate>20170418</metadataDate>
    </Table>
</metadata>
```

Example B.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
    <Table>
        <Citation>
            <Title>Template Title</Title>
            <Abstract>Template Abstract</Abstract>
            <Description>Template Description</Description>
        </Citation>
        <MetadataDate>20160131</MetadataDate>
    </Table>
</metadata>
```

The expected output of C.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
    <Table>
        <Name>SCHAME.table_name</Name>
        <Location>oracle:TNS_1</Location>
        <Citation>
            <Title>Title 1</Title>
            <Abstract>Template Abstract</Abstract>
            <Description>Template Description</Description>
        </Citation>
        <metadataDate>20170418</metadataDate>
    </Table>
</metadata>
```

Three things are important:

1. B can contain elements, which are not present in A but must be copied to C (eg metadata/Table/Citation/Abstract)
2. Elements of A with text must not be overwritten in C with text from B. (eg metadata/Table/Citation/Title). Then again empty elements in A must be filled with text from B (eg metadata/Table/Citation/Description)
3. The xml is just a sample, there are more than hundred different tags in my real xml files, these are just samples depicting my problem. So any solution to my problem has to be applicable on more tags than the ones living in my sample xml.

I do not need a running solution, any hints how to solve this for a XSLT beginner would be nice.

Comment: Do you need to perform this task generically, or can you rely on a known form for the desired output?  That is, would it be possible to write an XML file that could serve as an exhaustive fillable template for the desired output, with all possible elements represented?

Comment: I'd like to perform the task generically, as the xml is compliant to the INSPIRE metadata on geographic data. But our customer really needs a smaller subset of the complete specification, so I think I will create an exhaustive fillable template for our customers requirements. I will spend some more time deciding this question.
http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/documents/inspire-metadata-implementing-rules-technical-guidelines-based-en-iso-19115-and-en-iso-1

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how to identify **corresponding** elements in both files. I assume that each element appears at most once, so we can identify corresponding elements simply by their element name.
My solution follows the idea of John Bollinger:

1. Create a template.xml file containing **all** possible elements in the desired output structure.
2. The XSL script runs through all elements of the **template**.
3. It lookups the values of this element in files A and B.
4. If value A is not empty, take it, else take the value from B.

This is the template I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
    <Table>
        <Name/>
        <Location/>
        <Citation>
            <Title />
            <Abstract />
            <Description/>
        </Citation>
        <metadataDate/>
    </Table>
</metadata>
```

The following XSL has the above template as input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />        
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Parameters -->
    <xsl:param name="aFile"     select="'a.xml'" />
    <xsl:param name="bFile"     select="'b.xml'" />

    <!-- Variables -->
    <xsl:variable name="aDoc" select="document( $aFile, . )"/>
    <xsl:variable name="bDoc" select="document( $bFile, . )"/>

    <!-- Locate elements by name in both files -->
    <xsl:key name="elementsByName" match="*" use="name()" />

    <!-- Root-Template -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat( 'Merge of ', $aFile, ' with ', $bFile )" />
        </xsl:comment>

        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Merge all elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:variable name="elemName"   select="name()" />
        <xsl:variable name="aValue" select="$aDoc/key('elementsByName', $elemName)/text()" />
        <xsl:variable name="bValue" select="$bDoc/key('elementsByName', $elemName)/text()" />

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$aValue != ''">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$aValue" />
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="$bValue != ''">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$bValue" />
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of the transformation is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Merge of a.xml with b.xml-->
<metadata>
   <Table>
      <Name>SCHAME.table_name</Name>
      <Location>oracle:TNS_1</Location>
      <Citation>
         <Title>Title 1</Title>
         <Abstract>Template Abstract</Abstract>
         <Description>Template Description</Description>
      </Citation>
      <metadataDate>20170418</metadataDate>
   </Table>
</metadata>
```

The only "trick" in this code is the use of `xsl:key` and the corresponding `key()` function. This allows us to find the corresponding elements (same name) in both files A and B.

This script copies all elements from the template to the output file C.
To change this behaviour, simple move the `xsl:copy` instructions **inside** of the `xsl:when`.

Comment: I am afraid you may be oversimplifying the problem. An XML document can have more than one element with the same name, and in more than one place in the hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, I know. This is meant as example code. The author did not provide us with better criteria of what "corresponding" could mean in his context. ID attributes would be great, of course. Or you could try to take ancestors of elements into account (but this is guessing). Anyway, I wanted to give a starting point for him. But thanks for your hint, I should have made that clear from the start.

Comment: I don't think a truly generic solution is possible.

Comment: I think the generic solution would not work, because some tag names may appear more than once. Sorry for not saying this. I think I can generate a template will all fields for my customer, which can be used to merge two files A and B.

Answer (score 0):

I try to give an improved answer separately to avoid confusion with the helpful comments there.

In addition to the "generic" approach there (match element names), we will now have specific templates as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Parameters -->
    <xsl:param name="aFile"     select="'a.xml'" />
    <xsl:param name="bFile"     select="'b.xml'" />

    <!-- Variables -->
    <xsl:variable name="aDoc"   select="document( $aFile, . )"/>
    <xsl:variable name="bDoc"   select="document( $bFile, . )"/>

    <!-- Locate elements by name in both files -->
    <xsl:key name="elementsByName" match="*" use="name()" />

    <!-- Root-Template -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat( 'Merge of ', $aFile, ' with ', $bFile )" />
        </xsl:comment>

        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Merge specific elements -->
    <xsl:template match="metadata/Table/Description">
        <xsl:call-template name="mergeElement">
            <xsl:with-param name="aValue" select="$aDoc/metadata/Table/Description/text()" />
            <xsl:with-param name="bValue" select="$bDoc/metadata/Table/Description/text()" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="metadata/Table/Citation/Description">
        <xsl:call-template name="mergeElement">
            <xsl:with-param name="aValue" select="$aDoc/metadata/Table/Citation/Description/text()" />
            <xsl:with-param name="bValue" select="$bDoc/metadata/Table/Citation/Description/text()" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Merge unique elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*" priority="-10">
        <xsl:variable name="elemName"   select="name()" />

        <xsl:call-template name="mergeElement">
            <xsl:with-param name="aValue" select="$aDoc/key('elementsByName', $elemName)/text()" />
            <xsl:with-param name="bValue" select="$bDoc/key('elementsByName', $elemName)/text()" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Use A or B -->
    <xsl:template name="mergeElement">
        <xsl:param name="aValue" />
        <xsl:param name="bValue" />

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$aValue != ''">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$aValue" />
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="$bValue != ''">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$bValue" />
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For the test, I changed the template and A and B and added another Description element directly inside of Table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
    <Table>
        <Name />
        <Description/>  <!-- NEW: not unique element name -->
        <Location/>
        <Citation>
            <Title />
            <Abstract />
            <Description/>
        </Citation>
        <metadataDate/>
    </Table>
</metadata>
```

File A:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
    <Table>
        <Name>SCHAME.table_name</Name>
        <Location>oracle:TNS_1</Location>
        <Description>Table description A</Description> <!-- NEW -->
        <Citation>
            <Title>Title 1</Title>
            <Description/>
        </Citation>
        <metadataDate>20170418</metadataDate>
    </Table>
</metadata>
```

File B:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
    <Table>
        <Description>Table description B</Description> <!-- NEW -->
        <Citation>
            <Title>Template Title</Title>
            <Abstract>Template Abstract</Abstract>
            <Description>Template Description</Description>
        </Citation>
        <MetadataDate>20160131</MetadataDate>
    </Table>
</metadata>
```

Generated file C:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Merge of a.xml with b.xml-->
<metadata>
   <Table>
      <Name>SCHAME.table_name</Name>
      <Description>Table description A</Description> <!-- NEW -->
      <Location>oracle:TNS_1</Location>
      <Citation>
         <Title>Title 1</Title>
         <Abstract>Template Abstract</Abstract>
         <Description>Template Description</Description>
      </Citation>
      <metadataDate>20170418</metadataDate>
   </Table>
</metadata>
```

Obviosly, this is not a generic solution.
But if the number of non-unique elements is low compared to the total number, you will benefit from the generical template. Only the non-unique elements must be "styled" individually.